# How to do Bulk-insert from Huge JSON File (460 MB) in CouchDB

Tags: json, couchdb, bulkinsert

I need to do bulk-insert of document in my CouchDB database. 
I'm trying to follow the manual here:  http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API

Here is my script:

```
~$ DB="http://localhost:5984/employees"
~$ curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d @employees_selfContained.json -vX POST $DB/_bulk_docs
```

the file employees_selfContained.json is a huge file = 465 MB. I've validated it using JSONLint and found nothing wrong.

Here's the curl's verbose output:

```
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 5984 (#0)
* Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5984 (#0)
> POST /employees/_bulk_docs HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5984
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 439203931
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
* Closing connection #0
```

How can i do bulk-insert from that Huge single file? I prefer not to split the file into smaller size if possible..

EDIT: In case of someone wondering, I'm trying to convert this schema :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/sakila-structure.html
Into Self-contained document database, with structure like this:

```
{
    "docs": [
        {
            "emp_no": ..,
            "birth_date": ..,
            "first_name": ..,
            "last_name" : ..,
            "gender": ..,
            "hire_date": .., 
            "titles": 
                [
                    {
                    "title": ..,
                    "from_date": .., 
                    "to_date": ..
                    },
                    {..}
                ], 
            "salaries" : 
                [
                    {
                    "salary": ..,
                    "from_date": ..,
                    "to_date": ..
                    },
                    {..}                
                ], 
            "dept_emp": 
                [ 
                    {
                    "dept_no": ..,
                    "from_date": ..,
                    "to_date":
                    },
                    {..}
                ], 
            "dept_manager": 
                [ 
                    {
                    "dept_no": ..,
                    "from_date": ..,
                    "to_date": ..
                    },
                    {..}
                ], 
            "departments":
                [
                    {
                    "dept_no": .., 
                    "dept_name": ..
                    },
                    {..}
                ]
        } ,
        .
        .
        {..}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you check if anything appears in the CouchDB log ?

Comment: No. There's nothing to indicate the bulk-docs insert succeeded. 
I've tried using smaller JSON file (4K) and it run successfully

Comment: You may want to write a small Node.js script using the [JSONStream module](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream) so you can queue up documents for bulk-insertion in smaller batches, while still leaving your file intact.

Comment: 460MB huge? I'm currently trying to import a single 30 GB exported couchdb Json file into another instance. LOL. Yeah, as the answer says, you have to split it up. I use GoLang's bufio.Scanner to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the JSON and insert in batches of 10-50k documents.

Comment: Does that mean i have to split the file smaller one that contain 10-50k documents ? Can i just bulk-insert that huge file?

Comment: Ok. I'm splitting this document into 10-50k per documents. Any particular reasons why it has to be between 10-50k? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ShahrizalPrabowo I am pulling this out of ... the air but I think the HTTP interface will time-out if a post/put operation takes to long and fail.  So it's a time thing, I think.